# How to implement SparkSubmitOperator in Airflow

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, airflow

I have created an ec2 cluster in my aws account. I am connecting to this ec2 instance through ssh connection.

So, I have created a directory 'Airflow Project' in my C drive. I change to this directory and connect to the ec2 instance using ssh connection. This ec2 instance is ubuntu.

Now, I am connected to the ec2 instance. My home directory is /home/ubuntu. I have installed airflow and python here. I have also installed apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark.  I have created a dag inside airflow/dags directory. This dag uses SparkSubmitOperator to submit my spark job. I have created a spark application named python_script.py inside dags. I want to submit my spark application through this operator.

My question is:

1. Do I have to install Spark also even after installing apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark?
2. How to make Connection in Airflow UI to this SparkSubmitOperator?